# Circuit Breaker in a Microservices Architecture

Tags: microservices, hystrix, netflix, circuit-breaker

What is the best way to add a Circuit Breaker pattern in a Microservices Architecture. Should it be on the microservice side (inside each microservice), inside an ELB or insider the Api Gateway? What would be the best design pattern?

Answer (score 2):

I think is not use in each microservice, but in your BFF (backend for frontend) who use microservice. You can find a good implementation and exemple in this book https://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it. Solution with API Gateway is good, see Kong https://getkong.org/ for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the ref articles :)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 options (illustrated below). In the general case, the circuit breaker "protects" calls to an http service. If we think this service *is* the microservice, the circuit breaker is **never** in the microservice itself.

### API Gateway

In this case, you use an API gateway product that has circuit breaking support. Ambassador and Axway are examples. An alternative would be to provide circuit breaking in a BFF service that gets the calls to your backend service.

[image: breaker in api gateway]

### Service mesh

In this case, you use a service mesh product that has support for circuit breaking. Istio with Envoy are an example. In this example, the `insurance quote` service calls the `customer history` service. The proxy sidecar container does the circuit breaking.

[image: service mesh with circuit breaker]

### Circuit breaker lib

Here you use a library that provides circuit breaker support. Resilience4J is the one we use at work (in some Spring Boot apps that call http services).

[image: circuit breaker lib]

### Your design

Which is best? It depends on your application requirements and infrastructure constraints. Things to remember:

- Not all service interactions require circuit breaking.
- See if a fallback mechanism (e.g., default response) can be used when the circuit is open.
- Log/monitor circuit changes to detect problematic connections and services.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to delegate the circuit breaking concerns to a external library like Hystrix , rather than implementing it yourself.
Hystrix exposes a lot of properties that give you full control in tuning the circuit breaking capabilities.